# jQuery function not getting called in mvc text-changed event

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this strange behavior in jQuery when working with mvc application.

Below is MVC view in which I have implemented Text change event,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserId, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

[image]

```
    $("#UserId").change(function () {
        var UserId = $(this).val();
        //$("#txtName").val(emailId);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetValidUserName',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ UserId: UserId }),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!$.trim(data)) {
                    alert("User does not exist in system. Please enter valid User Id.");
                    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#UserId").val(data);
                    $("#UserId").focus();
                    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

While debugging application when I load Index view directly first time , jQuery function gets called and invoke the controller action properly.http://localhost:51012/UserApplication/Index

But when I load the view again, jQuery function doesn't get called.

Controller code,

```
 public JsonResult GetValidUserName(string userId)
    {
        LMTUsage objLMT = new LMTUsage();
        LMTDAL objLMTDAL = new LMTDAL();

        string UserID = "";

        objLMT.UserList = objLMTDAL.GetAll_User("", 0, "6");

        var AllUsersInDatabase = from p in objLMT.UserList
                                 where p.UserId == userId
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Name = p.UserName,
                                     Id = p.UserId,
                                 };

        foreach (var user in AllUsersInDatabase)
        {
            if (user.Name != null)
            {
                UserID = user.Id;
            }
        }
        return Json(UserID, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: `type: 'POST'` => are you sure the controller has `[HttpPost]` attribute? Also it's unnecessary to add `JSON.stringify` with `contentType`, just use `data: { UserId: UserId }` instead. Check if you're got any console errors too.

Comment: Where are you calling the change event? as a normal script or inside the document.ready method?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto. Yes I have made the necessary changes and still the same issue.

Comment: @mahlatse inside the document.ready method.

Comment: Probably you've mismatched parameter name: `data: { userId: UserId }`. Also use `type: GET` since you want to pass user ID through URL query string instead of `FormData`.

Comment: Its working now. Also added Controller name which was missing. var url2 = '@Url.Action("UserApplication_AddUserAccess", "UserApplication")';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with AJAX callback:

1) `type: 'POST'` option requires `[HttpPost]` attribute. If the attribute isn't present on the action method, use `type: 'GET'` instead.

2) You don't need `JSON.stringify()` to pass single parameter containing simple types (numeric and string values). A simple `{ userId: UserId }` should be fine.

3) The controller action's parameter name must be exactly match with parameter name sent from AJAX callback.

Therefore, your AJAX callback should be follow example below:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#UserId").change(function () {
        var UserId = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetValidUserName", "ControllerName")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { userId: UserId },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!$.trim(data)) {
                    alert("User does not exist in system. Please enter valid User Id.");
                    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
                }
                else {
                    $("#UserId").val(data);
                    $("#UserId").focus();
                    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```